# Does additive + commuting with homology imply exactness

Tags: abstract-algebra, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

For $F: C\rightarrow D$ an additive functor between abelian categories, one can show, by considering the LES of the SES of chain complexes $0\rightarrow Z_{\ast}\rightarrow C_{\ast}\rightarrow B_{\ast -1}$, that if $F$ is exact, then $F$ commutes with homology. What about the converse? Is an additive functor that preserves homology exact?

Comment: A trivial counterexample is the functor that sends every object and map to zero: this commutes with homology.

Comment: @peco This functor is exact. It even sends every sequence to an exact sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, consider an exact sequence $A \to B \to C$, then the homology of this as a chain complex at $B$ is zero, and so by additivity the homology of the chain complex $F(A) \to F(B) \to F(C)$ at $F(B)$ is also zero, but that means the sequence is exact.